# access variable from code behind page into aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, stringbuilder

I am trying to access variable from code behind page into aspx page that is in HTML type.
for that i am using the below code
**Note.** I m binding **StringBuilder** stored it in a variable and I am trying to access that variable in my aspx page.

```
<input type= "text" name="keyword" value = "<%=MyKeyword.ToString %>"/>
```

but it is showing Error like
**The name 'MyKeyword' does not exist in the current context**
I am also try to access through Javascript but showing same error.
can any body suggest what should i do?

Comment: Can you add the code. You wont be able to access a variable in the code behind from html unless you expose the variable somehow to the front end.

Comment: Is the stringbuilder declared as a protected/public variable?

Answer (score 1):

Declare `MyKeyword` with public access or create the `public` property.

```
public StringBuilder MyKeyword=new StringBuilder();
```